# How to do Insert-Select with manual incremental value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql databases

1. DB1
2. DB2

I want to select all contact values from **contact_mst** table under **DB1**, and then insert all those values inside **contact_mst** table under **DB2**. I do not want to copy the **contact_id** field for some reason and want to keep them incremental, but also do not want them to be **AUTO_INCREMENT** as I have used 2 primary keys **Company_id** which is 1 and **Contact_id** which is auto generated using php code for some specific purpose.

So I made a SQL query for transfering data like this :

```
INSERT INTO DB2.contactsmaster (Company_id, Contact_id, Contact_person)
   SELECT 1, (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Contact_id),0)+1 FROM DB2.contactsmaster), Contact_person FROM DB1.contact_mst;
```

Which I think I have done something wrong, as this will not generate new IDS each time and in place will return **Contact_id** as 1 every time.

Any suggestion? 
P.S. I just want to achieve this using SQL Query only. I know I can do this with PHP code but actually I want to supply .sql file to my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the sample code for inserting records to table tab2 where value of column `a` is a sequence of integer and value of column b is same as value of column b of tab1

```
create table tab1
(
  a int,
  b int
);

create table tab2
(
   a int,
   b int
);


insert into tab1
values
(10,20),(30,40);
```

tab1 contents:

```
| a | b |
---------
|10 |20 |
|30 |40 |

insert into tab2
select  @row := @row + 1, b  FROM tab1 , (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

tab2 contents:

```
| a | b |
---------
|1  |20 |
|2  |40 |
```

Check the working of the query at sqlfiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f9a39/1

Let me know if it solved your problem or not.

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO DB2.contactsmaster (Company_id, Contact_id, Contact_person) 
       VALUES(
              1, 
              (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Contact_id),0)+1 FROM DB2.contactsmaster),
              (SELECT Contact_person FROM DB1.contact_mst LIMIT 1)
             )
```

Comment: this is going to be pretty slow if I use it this way as the actual table has 16 fields, I want to copy data from all those fields. Here I used 3 fields just to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

To insert record with seprate key generate you need to use trigger for insert key

create bellow trigger in db2

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `contactsmaster `
 FOR EACH ROW 
set new.Contact_id =(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Contact_id),0)+1 FROM contactsmaster)
DELIMITER ;
```

after trigger created execute bellow sql

```
INSERT INTO DB2.contactsmaster (Company_id, Contact_person)
   SELECT 1, Contact_person FROM DB1.contact_mst;
```